# Connect to machine that is behind another machine

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, router, subnet

I have the following setup LAN setup (All machines are running Slackware 14.2):

```
                  INTERNET
                      |
                      | 192.168.10.1
                 +----------+
                 |ISP ROUTER|
                 +----------+
                   |      |
              +----+      +-----+
192.168.10.10 | (eth0)          | 192.168.10.20 (eth0)
         +--------+         +--------+
         | HOST A |         | HOST B |
         +--------+         +--------+
                                | 192.168.50.50 (eth1)
                                |
                                | 192.168.50.100 (eth0)
                            +--------+
                            | HOST C |
                            +--------+
```

`HOST A` and `HOST B` are connected via my ISP's router and can connect to each other. `HOST C` is only connected to `HOST B` and is able to talk to `HOST B`. However, I would like to be able to connect to `HOST C` from `HOST A`. I cannot configure my ISP's router. `HOST A` and `HOST B` must be able to connect to the Internet, so changing the default Gateway to anything else than my ISP's router is not an option. `HOST C` shall not be allowed to make any connection to the Internet.

I think that at least on `HOST B` I have to apply these `iptables` rules:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.50.100 -d 192.168.10.0/24 -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.50.100 -s 192.168.10.0/24 -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.50.100 -d 192.168.10.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

However, I am not sure if these rules are sufficient for `HOST B` and I do not know how to configure `HOST A`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further research I found the solution. First, `HOST B` has to be configured to forward packets from and to `HOST C`:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.50.100 -d 192.168.10.0/24 -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.50.100 -s 192.168.10.0/24 -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.50.100 -d 192.168.10.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Then `HOST A` **and** `HOST C` need to add additional routes via `HOST B`, so they can find each other.

On `HOST A` issue as root:

```
route add -host 192.168.50.100 gw 192.168.10.20
```

On `HOST C` issue as root:

```
route add -host 192.168.10.10 gw 192.168.50.50
```

That is all. Potential Firewalls on any of the involved hosts must be, of course, configured accordingly to allow traffic.

Comment: I believe you can accept your answer to this question...

Answer (score -1):

You're hosed.  Without the ability to configure HOST A *or* the ISP router, you can't do this.

If/when you can configure HOST A, you can give it a more specific (i.e. non-default) route for 192.168.50.0/24 and point that at HOST B as the next hop, then use iptables on HOST B to forward to (and from) HOST C.  This is the slightly cleaner way of doing it, since you'd completely bypass the ISP router.

If/when you can configure ISP ROUTER, you can tell it that the network 192.168.50.0/24 exists (it does not know this today) and to get there it needs to send traffic via HOST B.  (aside: in this case the ISP router *should* send an [ICMP redirect](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/13714-43.html) back to HOST A when it receives traffic destined for C.)

So in summary you have an unsolvable problem in that ***neither*** HOST A nor the ISP router have knowledge of this other subnet.  Until you break that logjam in one way or another, you're outta luck.

Also, your iptables statements imply that you're strictly trying to forward packets for only HOST C -- if you ever plan to put more devices on that subnet you may want to think about building a forwarding rule for the whole /24 subnet rather than just that one host.

Comment: I can configure HOST A. I just do not know how, i.e., what would the `iptables` rule would look like or what other commands would I need to issue. Only the ISP router is off-limits.